# how can i change the color of a row of a dxdatagrid (jquery) based on the value contained in another column

Tags: jquery, devextreme

How can i change the color of a row of a dxdatagrid (jquery) based on the value contained in another column example : value = 1 green line, value = 0 red line.

Answer (score 0):

To change styles of an entire row, use the [`onCellPrepared`](https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/ApiReference/UI_Components/dxDataGrid/Configuration/#onCellPrepared) event.

Example:

```js
$(() => {
  $('#gridContainer').dxDataGrid({
    dataSource: customers,
    keyExpr: 'ID',
    columns: ['ID', 'CompanyName', 'City', 'State', 'Phone', 'Fax'],
    showBorders: true,
    onCellPrepared: (ev) => {
      if (ev.rowType !== 'data') return;
      if (ev.data.ID < 5) {
        ev.cellElement.css('background-color', 'red');
      } else {
        ev.cellElement.css('background-color', 'green');
      }
    }
  });
});
```